# IE 9 border radius not working with PIE.js

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I m trying to apply border radius using PIE.js file

Code :

```
$(function()
{
    if (window.PIE)
    {
        $('div').each(function()
        {
            alert("Welcome");
            PIE.attach(this);
        });
    }
});
```

above code not working, if block is not executing dont know why any solution

Answer (score 4):

IE9 already have support for **CSS** `border-radius` property. You do not need to add PIE.htc for that.

Comment: not working. i tried that first and then i found out about PIE.js file

Answer (score 1):

Some time you will have to apply position:relative to attache PIE.htc.

Try to apply this:

```
div {position:relative;}
```

It will work.